# How large and tall can a bipedal, upright standing, mostly herbivorous therapod get?

Tags: science-based, biology, creature-design, anatomy, dinosaurs

I was originally gonna post this as one question with my previous one, but since these are two different topics I've decided to split them.

Previous question: [What is the best Foot shape for a Bidepal uprighting standing dinosaur?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/253337/what-is-the-best-foot-shape-for-a-bidepal-uprighting-standing-dinosaur/253340#253340)

Previously, I asked what was the best foot shape and type for a semi-aquatic therapod that grazes the tops of trees and hunts fish in shallow water.

Now I want to know if these creatures may undergo gigantism similar to sauropods and even modern day grazers, and how tall they would get if so.

As a semi-aquatic animal it should still be able to float and dive without trouble.

Or at least travel through water similar to hippos and crocodiles.

And similarly to birds they may have had hollow bones and air sacs like some dinosaurs were thought to have.

Would they be able to get as tall as mega-sauropods are long? (Though there length is contributed mostly in there long necks and tails.)

Comment: Not really, for one humans don't have a tail to act as a counterweight and two, Therizinosaurus and Deinocheirus seemed to be able to reach around 6 meters or 19 feet tall http://www.prehistoric-wildlife.com/images/species/t/therizinosaurus-size.jpg http://www.prehistoric-wildlife.com/images/species/d/deinocheirus-size.jpg then again I could be wrong comparing the two cause there bodies are somewhat horizontal and close to the ground, unlike say an emperor penguin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be as large and tall as it's food supply, predator avoidance/combat and environment support.

With height, it's pointless to be higher than necessary. Because normally your water supply is ground level. So giraffes for instance don't grow much higher than their food sources and have to do some gymnastics when drinking.

Weight is the same, if you're buoyed up by water you can be pretty heavy and still agile. It would make more sense to be eating water plants though instead of tree tops.

Sauroposeidon was the tallest dinosaur at 18+ metres, not an obligate biped of course, but indicative of what can be achieved, with many others around 13 metres. They all had very long necks though.